# Interrupt all events in a page

Tags: c#, events, methods, windows-phone-8.1, dispose

I have a problem with methods called by events in a page for a Windows Phone 8.1 application. I have four PivotItems in my page which each fire a method (`PivotX.Loaded += LEvents;`) like this on Loaded:

```
private async void LEvents(object SENDER, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // Download Data
    // Extract Data
    // Put Data in The GridViews (LOOP)
}
```

But when I leave that page, and clear the cache (so the page is disposed), the methods are still running, causing conflicts and exceptions.
Obviously, putting data inside GVs isn't taking a big deal of time comparing to Download and Extract operations, so I need to stop the whole function in a forceful way.

Is there a way to stop all running threads, methods or events on a page before disposing it?

If not, event stopping them one by one is an idea, but just **stop** them.

Comment: What do you mean methods are still running? Do they have some kind of loop inside or what they are doing?

Comment: @Mino : they're just async, each of them has a foreach inside, yes, but not  an infinite loop.

Comment: You need to have some sort of abort flag (or cancellation token) that you check within your loops and exit if the flag is set.

Answer (score 1):

If you are connecting to events like this:

```
  Loaded += Page_Loaded;
```

then you may want to detach the handler in the OnNavigatedFrom() method:

```
  Loaded -= Page_Loaded;
```

As for interrupting all running threads that started for this page ..
I am not aware of any connection made between threads that are created and a page. So you will have to manage that manually - instead of calling "await SomeAsyncMethod()", you will have to get the task, store it in a collection, and when the page is closed, iterate the collection and cancel any tasks that are not finished. Something like this:

```
Task task = SomeAsyncMethod();
task.Start();
tasks.Add(task);
...

OnNavigatedFrom() 
{
   foreach (var task in tasks)
   {
      if (!task.IsCancelled && !task.IsCompleted)
          task.AsAsyncAction().Cancel();
    }
}

But I have not tested it and I do not guarantee this will work
```

Comment: Does it terminate the subscripted method? That's what I'm looking for.

Comment: This *seems* to have solved the problem, thanks a lot!

Comment: This is not a solution, async methods seem not to stop this way.

Comment: if you have foreach loops in your async methods, the you can put a member variable like "bool stopProcessing", set this variable to true in the OnNavigatedFrom method and in the loops check the variable and break the loop if it is set to true

Comment: Thanks for the idea, but the loop is not the problem, I'll update the question with further info, but just telling you, the loop even takes less than 500ms.

Comment: seems to be working, anyway, isn't there any other way than launching async methods and catching the Task object?
Methods I use are directly called by events. Anyway thanks, I'll test it.